# Connect a variable integer to a radio button value

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button, tkinter-entry, tkinter-button

I am trying to make a program which could use a standard load by clicking the standload radiobutton or a variable load by clicking the variable load radiobutton. This variable load can be chosen by filling in a entry. Unfortunetely, I am not able to load the entry value directly into the value for the radiobutton. If I select the standard load it is working, but for the variable load I always obtain zero. Can someone show me what I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance!! The following code is what I have:

```
selectedload = tk.IntVar()

rad_standload = ttk.Radiobutton(tab1, text='Standard load (20 kN/m2)', value=pfloor,      variable=selectedload)
rad_standload.grid(row=17, column=1, sticky='W')

entry_int_frload = tk.IntVar()
entry_frload = ttk.Entry(master = tab1, textvariable = entry_int_frload)
entry_frload.grid(row=17, column=3, sticky='W')

rad_standloadfr = ttk.Radiobutton(tab1, text="Distributed load [kN/m2]:", value=entry_int_frload.get(),   variable=selectedload)
rad_standloadfr.grid(row=17, column=2, sticky="E")
```

I tried to create a function to put the .get() function in, but it is still not working. Hope that someone knows the answer.

Comment: This isn't very clear. You mentioned that you attempted to resolve this with a function, but there isn't a function in your example. It's better to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can copy and paste your failed attempt. It's likely that you are calling the `get` method too soon before a value is bound to your `IntVar`.

Comment: https://ibb.co/xXzyL93. The grid isn't correct layout. the correct is rad_standload.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='W')  entry_frload.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky='W')  rad_standloadfr.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="E"). But what is pfloor is?

Comment: You will have to write two functions Standard_load  and Distributed_load.

Comment: What is value of m2?

Answer (score 0):

You can *trace* the tkinter variable `entry_int_frload` and update the *`value`* option of `rad_standloadfr`:

```py
def update_rad_standloadfr(*args):
    try:
        # change the value option of rad_standloadfr
        rad_standloadfr.config(value=entry_int_frload.get())
    except tk.TclError as ex:
        print(ex)

# call update_rad_standloadfr() whenever entry_int_frload is changed
entry_int_frload.trace_add("write", update_rad_standloadfr)
```

Note that `rad_standloadfr` will be deselected if it is currently selected after changing its *value* option.